# change permission folder Codeigniter

Tags: php, permissions, image-uploading, codeigniter-3

I want to change the permission for a folder (big_pics) to mode 777.

```
function do_upload(){
    $config['upload_path']  = './big_pics/';
    $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']  = 100;
    $config['max_width']  = 1024;
    $config['max_height']  = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        foreach($error as $key => $value){
            echo $value."<br>";
        }
        //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }else{
        echo "Well DOne";
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

The folder is positioned on root folder.
I use codeigniter for this project

Comment: What does the code have to do with changing the permissions on a directory?

Comment: Improved grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permission of your file or folder by using this before upload.

```
$frdata = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); // get data
$frfile = $frdata ['upload_data']['full_path']; // get file path
chmod($frfile, 0777); // CHMOD file
 if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) { 
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else { 
    $file_name = $this->upload->data();
    }
```